# Convert XML date and time to Tdatetime in Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, parsing, date

I am consuming a webservice/soap and loading XML tables for a clientdataset, I have a node with dates in this format:

**`2014-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-02:00`**

I am trying to convert this type of data for regional my type, I'm using this:

```
class function TDateConvert.DateTimeFromIso8601(const Value: string): TDateTime;
begin
  with TXSDateTime.Create() do
  try
    XSToNative(value); // convert from WideString
    Result := AsDateTime; // convert to TDateTime  finally
  finally
    Free();
  end;
end;
```

I'm getting, but the date is coming wrong, using that example above instead of returning 01/01/2014 31/12/2013 is returning, this is the date format used in Brazil (dd/MM/YYYY).

How can I solve this? It has to do with my regional settings (Brazil)?

**EDIT**

I have to use the function Timezonebias from IdGlobalProtocols to correct the date, follow below the function to help someone:

```
class function TDateConvert.DateTimeFromIso8601(const Value: string): TDateTime;
begin
  with TXSDateTime.Create() do
  try
    XSToNative(value); // convert from WideString
    Result := AsDateTime+TimeZoneBias; // convert to TDateTime  finally with sum of timezone bias
  finally
    Free();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you are going to use Indy anyway, you might consider letting it parse the input string as well, such as with its `GMTToLocalDateTime()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have UTC `-02:00` in your time part and when time is converted to local time your date ends up to be day before.

Comment: You are right, I googling and found www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html,I found Timezonebias const from  IdGlobalProtocols unit and sum in result of function.